# Setting a datatable cell value using LINQ according to some conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to set a true boolean value to a cell in datatable according to some conditions using LINQ.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtLeftResult.Rows)
        {
            var shipNo = dr[0].ToString();   
            var invoiceNo = dr[1].ToString();   

            var res = dtInvoicesList.Rows
            .Cast<DataRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Field<string>("[Shipment#]") == shipNo && r.Field<string>("[Invoice#]") == invoiceNo)
            .Select(r => r.Field<string>("IsValid")).First();
        }
```

I need to set the IsValid field (boolean) to true after finding the correcet row in the datatable. I am finding the row but I am not able to set the value.

How can I do it?

Comment: if your object "res"  has that row in the above code, then you can use it to set the value. 
res["IsValid"] = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `res` variable is the value of *IsValid* because of your call to `Select(...)`

What you want to do is get the row:

```
var row = dtInvoicesList.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("[Shipment#]") == shipNo 
        && r.Field<string>("[Invoice#]") == invoiceNo)
    .First();
```

And set its value: `row["IsValid"] = true;`

Answer (score 1):

`Select` statement in your query returns the value of a cell, what you want is the `DataRow` of the `DataTable`.

Modify your query to get filtered rows and then access the `DataRow` columns using *columnname* or *Index*.

```
var firstMatch = dtInvoicesList.Rows
                    .AsEnumerable()Where(r => r.Field<string>("[Shipment#]") == shipNo && r.Field<string>("[Invoice#]") == invoiceNo)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
if(firstMatch!= null)
{
    firstMatch["IsValid"] = true; //new value.
}
```